# Optimize xslt xpath matching expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

My xpath expression evaluation is taking bulk of the time while converting xml to another format. After going through couple of articles on web, i realise there might be an opportunity to improve my xpath expression but I am completely new xslt. If someone can help to optimize following xpath that will be helpful or if you can confirm whether there is a scope of improvement or not.

Also, there are repetaed patterns of xpath across xslt

```
<xsl:template
    match="h1:Document/h1:component/h1:Body/h1:component/h1:section[h1:code/@code='1234']">
    <xsl:element name="eSection">
        <xsl:if test="h1:text">
            <xsl:element name="sectionT">
                <xsl:copy-of select="h1:text"
                    copy-namespaces="no" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="h1:entry">
            <xsl:element name="sectionE">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template
    match="h1:Document/h1:component/h1:Body/h1:component/h1:section[h1:code/@code='6789']">

    <xsl:element name="mSection">
        <xsl:if test="h1:text">
            <xsl:element name="sectionT">
                <xsl:copy-of select="h1:text"
                    copy-namespaces="no" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="h1:entry">
            <xsl:element name="sectionE">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Profiling details:

[image]

Comment: Have you measured and profiled that complete XSLT stylesheet to check whether that particular template is the culprit of performance problems?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, did profiling using Oxygen.

Comment: Then show us the relevant details of the profiling output, show us some details about the size of the input, the performance details like complete execution time, time spent in that particular template.

Comment: I am testing with small xml around 500KB but in production size of xml is around 4 MB and there are multiple such documents. I have added the profiling details. have a look.

Comment: Multiple documents during a single stylesheet run? In that case you need to show some more context as to where/how you load/process them.

Comment: How long is the total transformation time? Is the performance actually a problem? How does the transformation time increase with document size? What XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Given `h1:Document/h1:component/h1:Body/h1:component/h1:section[h1:code/@code='1234']` it might make sense to try a key `<xsl:key name="section-by-code" match="h1:Document/h1:component/h1:Body/h1:component/h1:section" use="h1:code/@code"/>` and then

```
<xsl:template match="key('section-by-code', '1234')">
  <eSection>
    <xsl:where-populated>
      <sectionT>
         <xsl:copy-of select="h1:text"
                    copy-namespaces="no" />
      </sectionT>
    </xsl:where-populated>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="h1:entry"/>
  </eSection>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1:entry">
  <sectionE>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no" />
  </sectionE>
</xsl:template>
```